# Can't understand why my Haskell API call script returns "Nothing"

Tags: api, haskell

I am super new to Haskell and trying to write an API integration worker that grabs data from Quandl.

This is my main.hs file:

```
module Main where

import Data.Quandl

main = do
    result <- getTable "EOD" "AAPL" (Just "my_key")
    print result
```

When I run it in ghci like this:

```
Prelude> :l main
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( main.hs, interpreted )
*Main> main
```

It seems to do something behind the schenes for a few seconds, then it returns this:

```
Nothing
```

Does anyone know why this might be?

Comment: Have you checked the documentation? https://hackage.haskell.org/package/quandl-api-0.2.1.0/docs/Data-Quandl.html The function you’re using is the first one described.

Comment: Yes, I saw that.  I am so new to this that I don't know what to do with that information.  I'm guessing that "EOD" is the incorrect "source" name, but I'm not sure how to find the correct list of source names.

Comment: https://www.quandl.com/search is where you can search for a Quandl source/code

Comment: Right, but for example I am testing it with this: https://www.quandl.com/data/EOD-End-of-Day-US-Stock-Prices/documentation -- and I see that I could change the parameters to `EOD/MSFT`, but I don't know what to replace `getTable` with.

Comment: So what is the actual *single* question you have?

Comment: Assuming `getTable` is the command I want, I don't know how to identify the string that Quandl uses to identify the EOD source.

Comment: Even when I use the FRED/GDP example in the hackage docs, I get `Nothing` back.

Comment: You're not literally using `"my_key"`, are you? I suspect that supposed to be some sort of API key

Comment: No, I wasn't.  It turned out that there was an issue with the Hackage version of the API.  I cloned from GitHub and it worked :)